# Create buttons from Database dynamically (REST)

Tags: java, android, xml

My goal is to create an android app that requires minimal update in form of Java code, in order to do the same in Swift for iOS as well..

My first plan was to connect through my MySQL-database but upon learned that is not a secure way to do it. I want to dynamically add buttons from a database.

What I understand I can do it through an REST API I myself can build it in PHP but how do I implement that kind of feature to add buttons upon the response from the server? To dynamically add 2,3,4 or 8 buttons in the app from the response with the data providen?

Can I as well create the fragments dynamically for each button from just updating the database instead of writing the code yet again for another button and fragment?

EDIT: The main goal is to update the app in a way like WebView, to not need to add code for each fragment, button etc every time it gets updated rather update through updating the database it get it's information from